# Process substitution command in . ebextensions

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to install Netdata in my aws beanstalk instances. I created a config file in my `.ebextensions` folder

```
container_commands:
  00install:
    command: "bash <(curl -Ss https://my-netdata.io/kickstart.sh) --dont-wait"
    ignoreErrors: true
```

When the command gets ran on deploy beanstalk logs this error.

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `bash <(curl -Ss https://my-netdata.io/kickstart.sh) --dont-wait'
```

I had no idea what <() meant so I looked it up and saw it was `process substitution`. From what I understood process substitution can be rewriting using plain pipes.

For example

`more <( ls /usr/bin )`

Could be

`ls /usr/bin | more`

In my command I'm also passing in flags so I was having issues gettin the piped version of the command working.

**NOTE**: The root problem is beanstalk telling me its confused about the parenthesis. My solution was just transforming the command to use regular pipes. However, if anyone knows just how I write this command on the beanstalk config to get it working that would be awesome.

Comment: Probably the parenthesis aer being interpreted by the shell that is reading the file, not by the `bash` that you are intending to use. Try using single quotes to avoid the external shell trying to perform the substitution. Or escape the parenthesis if the single quotes doen't work.

Comment: BTW, `ls /usr/bin | more` is different from `more <( ls /usr/bin )`. In the first case, the standard input is being used, in the second case, the standard input is free and the data is read from another file descriptor. It would be more similar to `mkfifo tmp; ls /usr/bin > tmp& more /tmp; rm tmp`

Comment: to add to the first comment, note that your error message begins with ``/bin/sh:`. This is the program reporting the error. It doesn't know how to deal with the `(`, after the `<` , its "parser" doesn't know about `<(...)`. Given that you are 3,4? levels deep in OS/shells, can't really advise how to fix this in the `aws/beanstalk` context. I would see if I could make the default shell to be `/path/to/bash` and that will allow you more freedom. But there are different features available in different versions of bash, so you'll need to be aware of those limitations too. Good luck.

Comment: @Poshi I tried using single quotes `'bash <(curl -Ss https://my-netdata.io/kickstart.sh) --dont-wait'` and escaping the parenthesis `'bash <\(curl -Ss https://my-netdata.io/kickstart.sh\) --dont-wait'`. Unfortunately no luck with either approach